# Dictionary to DataFrame Pandas: Error: 6 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns. - While loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert a python dictionary to a pandas DataFrame, but as the dictionary values are not of the same length, when I do:

```
recomm = pd.DataFrame(recommendation.items(),columns=['id','recId1','recId2','recId3','recId4','recId5'])
```

I get:

> 6 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns

which mean that one of the provided values is of length 2.

To correct it, I did:

```
for key in recommendation.keys():
    while True:
        l1 = recommendation[key]
        l1.append(0)
        recommendation[key] = l1
        if len(l1) < 5:
            break
```

But I still get the error when converting to DF.

I checked the dictionary as follow:

```
 for key in recommendation.keys():
    if len(recommendation[key]) != 5:
        print key
```

and discovered that 0 was added to those of length 5 too. means I'm now having some of the values with 6 as length.
e.g dictionary value:

> [12899423, 12907790, 12443129, 12558006, 12880407, 0]

How to correct the while code so that it **ONLY** adds 0 to the list of values if the length of the list is **< 5.**

and is there a better way to convert the dictionary to pandas DataFrame?
Dictionary keys are: int and str.

Comment: To create a pandas dataframe you don't need to call `.items()` to the dict, just directly pass the dict

Comment: doesn't resolve. same error even if I remove `.items()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following :

**In python 2.7 use iteritems() as it return an iterator over the dictionary, in python 3.x, items() have the same behavior**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Your dictionary
d = dict( A = np.array([1,2]), B = np.array([1,2,3,4]) )

df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems() ]))
```

It will fill the dataframe with NaN values for the missing entries, then you just have to call the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function :

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Your missing data will now be filled with zeros

Comment: I also thought about converting to DF and then fillna and applied this `df_rec = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(recommendation, orient='index', dtype=None)` but then didn't know how to change the index to index in range [0,1,2,...] not the dictionary keys.

Comment: to reset an index you can use Dataframe.reset_index(drop=True), it will make your index go from 0 to n-1

Comment: I tried with your suggested solution and got >MemoryError maybe because the length of the dictionary is 29000.

Comment: This should not append unless you run your code on something with very low resources i think, could you share the data you are using ?

As a less elegant solution, you could try to initialise an empty (full of 0) dataframe. Add column with the name of your dictionary keys and length of the biggest column you have. Then fill the column with a loop.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the resources, as before I applied `from_dict` on the same dictionary without any MemoryError but when I repeated it now, it ran into it. I will restart the Notebook Kernel and repeat.